# mysql: INSERT INTO Query

Tags: mysql, insert, syntax-error

i'm trying to insert some values into a mysql database using a shell script. The script generates the following query for the database:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE p_devices (p_device_id,p_device_name)
VALUES (1,'raw_dishwasher_neff_s42t69n3_auto3545_-.csv');
```

Unfortunately I get an Error...

> ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax;
>   check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the
>   right syntax to use near 'TABLE p_devices (p_device_id,p_device_name)
>   VALUES (1,'raw_dishwasher_neff_s42t6' at line 1

The Table p_devices is built through the following command:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS p_devices
(
        p_device_id INT,
        p_device_name VARCHAR(255),
        p_device_manufacturer VARCHAR(255),
        p_device_class VARCHAR(255),
        PRIMARY KEY (p_device_id)
);
```

Is there anyone able to tell me what I'm doing wrong? I'm pretty new to mySQL so it might be a really stupid mistake but well ... been looking for the past hour without success...

Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

`INSERT INTO foo`, not `INSERT INTO TABLE foo`.

General tip: The SQL snippets that MySQL uses in its error messages usually START at the exact point the syntax error occured. Since your message started with `TABLE`, that'd be your clue to look at that part of the query.

Comment: Thank you very much... Must have owerseen it every time I checked the syntax - got confused with TABLE and table_name...